# Couchbase storing List values wrongly

Tags: java, serialization, couchbase

Basically I have a simple POJO class which has some variables. Whenever I try using .save() it saves all values fine except for List<> values. Im storing to couchbase and the end result is something like this:

```
  "location": "location",
  "categories": {
    "empty": false
  }
```

Categories is a List and what I pass into my Postman body is:

```
"categories": [
  "OneTwoThree"
  ]
```

but as you can see the serialization isnt done correct and I always get the `"empty": false` even if its my own class or a String. Any ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: Hi, can you you share the code that writes the document to Couchbase?

Answer (score 1):

This is https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACOUCH-560. It is fixed in the working 4.1.0 snapshot and will be in the upcoming 4.0.2 release scheduled for tomorrow.